# How do I get rid of jagged edges on my model with OpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl

I am using OpenGL to render 3D models, but there is a strange graphical glitch that seems to be occurring. Whenever a darker color is drawn over a lighter color, the edges are very jagged. As the camera moves, these jagged edges will expand and contract sort of like a sine wave that varies frequency with time.

Here is an image of the effect:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDmbB.jpg

The following is the OpenGL setup code I have used:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE)
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL) 
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)

# Define tessalation object and callbacks
self.tessellator = gluNewTess()
gluTessCallback(self.tessellator, GLU_TESS_BEGIN, glBegin)
gluTessCallback(self.tessellator, GLU_TESS_END, glEnd)
gluTessCallback(self.tessellator, GLU_TESS_VERTEX, glVertex3dv)
```

Is there any good way to avoid this issue so these graphical errors don't appear? I have tried enabling/disabling certain features but none that I've tried have resulted in a fix, and I'm not sure what type of setting this would fall under (if any).

I have also tried scaling up the image (both by 10 times and 100 times). The effect is not as noticeable but still apparent, and this is not ideal given the way the rest of the program is currently working.

Comment: This isn't normal aliasing, I can say that much. Perhaps there's some Z-fighting going on?

Comment: Looks like you would be drawing two polygons at the same place, which causes problems with depth buffer and floats. You need to move the topmost polygons a little bit off the lower polygons

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen When you say two polygons at the same place, do you mean the same coordinates in the 3D space or the same region graphically on the screen? I'm not sure how I'd move the topmost polygons "a little bit off" the lower ones besides by increasing their z-value but that would change dimensions I don't want to change.

Comment: Yes, I mean they are on exactly the same plane. This causes the depth check to have almost same values due to floats and the polygons "fight" which shall remain visible. Usually the solution is to separate them a tiny amount, if the both have to exist, or eliminate the polygons underneath if they're never actually shown.

Comment: Perhaps it is hard to tell but the smallest rectangles are just transparent surfaces that act as windows. The model is just a simple wedge/ramp shape and no two surfaces have any overlap besides the edges where they connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen when you lose precision in your Z buffer. The range of Z values in which you draw your scene is too narrow compared the the complete range of possible values in the Z axis.

Try to adjust the Z-near and Z-far in your projection matrix to be closer to the Z values that occur in the scene and see if it makes a difference.

More specifically, you need to avoid Z-near being equal to 0.0
More info here: https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems this is probably the issue, as changing zNear/zfar has affected the outcome. However, I have only been able to find values that make the issue worse. My zNear was set at 1.0, and zFar was 10000. The z-values in my model generally range between 0.0 and 5.0. I have lowered zFar down by factors of 10 until with no noticeable change until I got to 10, at which point nothing displayed at all. Lowering zNear to 0.1 while keeping zFar around 100 made the issue much worse. Any tips for determining reasonable values for these two parameters?

Comment: @samalamma708 You would want to make zNear larger to improve the quality, not smaller. That said, using 1.0 for zNear and 100 for zFar should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I increased zNear to 10 and and changed zFar to about 10000 and now the problem only persists if you zoom in pretty far. Woohoo!